# How to declare a static variable with class.js?

Tags: javascript, class, oop

I use class.js, by John Resig:

```
/* Simple JavaScript Inheritance
 * By John Resig http://ejohn.org/
 * MIT Licensed.
 */
// Inspired by base2 and Prototype
var initializing = false, fnTest = /xyz/.test(function(){xyz;}) ? /\b_super\b/ : /.*/;

// The base Class implementation (does nothing)
Class = function() {};

// Create a new Class that inherits from this class
Class.extend = function(prop) {
    var _super = this.prototype;

    // Instantiate a base class (but only create the instance,
    // don't run the init constructor)
    initializing = true;
    var prototype = new this();
    initializing = false;

    // Copy the properties over onto the new prototype
    for (var name in prop) {
        // Check if we're overwriting an existing function
        prototype[name] = typeof prop[name] == "function" &&
            typeof _super[name] == "function" && fnTest.test(prop[name]) ?
            (function(name, fn){
                return function() {
                    var tmp = this._super;

                    // Add a new ._super() method that is the same method
                    // but on the super-class
                    this._super = _super[name];

                    // The method only need to be bound temporarily, so we
                    // remove it when we're done executing
                    var ret = fn.apply(this, arguments);
                    this._super = tmp;

                    return ret;
                };
            })(name, prop[name]) :
            prop[name];
    }

    // The dummy class constructor
    Class = function () {
        // All construction is actually done in the init method
        if ( !initializing && this.init )
            this.init.apply(this, arguments);
    }

    // Populate our constructed prototype object
    Class.prototype = prototype;

    // Enforce the constructor to be what we expect
    Class.constructor = Class;

    // And make this class extendable
    Class.extend = arguments.callee;

    return Class;
};

if(!(typeof exports === 'undefined')) {
    exports.Class = Class;
}
```

How do I use this to declare a static variable in a new class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "static" you mean class-wide, you just assign it as a property on your "class" (constructor function), e.g.:

```
var Thingy = Class.extend({
    init: function() {
        // ...
    }
});
Thingy.myStaticVariable = "foo";
```

You have to use the fully-qualified name when using it.

Of course, you could create "static" variables by creating a context that you close over:

```
var Thingy = (function() {
    var myStaticVariable = "foo";

    return Class.extend({
        init: function() {
            // ...
        }
    });
});
```

...and then it's A) Truly private to your "class," and B) Available without the class prefix.

---

No answer in this topic would be really complete without mentioning that Resig's SJI is extremely basic and quite dated. These days, I'd suggest using ES2015 (ES6) semantics and a decent transpiler (I use [Babel](http://babeljs.io)). I was frankly never happy about SJI using function decompilation to handle supercalls, particularly as it wasn't rigorous and could easily be confused by the word "super" appearing in string literals, so I [wrote my own thing instead](https://code.google.com/p/lineagejs/) (also now outdated by ES2015). Amusingly, though, ES2015 class semantics only provide for static *methods*, not static variables, and so you end up doing the same sorts of things as the above:

```
class Thingy {
    constructor() {
        // ...
    }
});
Thingy.myStaticVariable = "foo";
```

or

```
let Thingy = (function() {
    let myStaticVariable = "foo";

    class Thingy {
        constructor() {
            // ...
        }
    }

    return Thingy;
})();
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out what I mean, thats the exact result I was thinking about, but do you have to declare it outside the Class.extend {...}?

Comment: @Murplyx: Yes, although my second example above contains it a fair bit. You have to understand that Resig's SJI is **extremely** basic and quite dated.

Comment: @Murplyx: [ES2015](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html), which defines `class` semantics (99% syntactic sugar [but, you know, really *good* sugar], 1% language plumbing that isn't just sugar to allow for subclassing things like arrays).

Comment: @Murplyx: (Just noticed this.) I should mention that your edit to the above was rejected (by the community) because it was incorrect. In that pre-ES2015 example using Resig's SJI, `var myStaticVariable` is the correct way to have a "static" (class-wide) variable for the code in `Thingy`.

Comment: When I mean "static" I mean like this: http://pastebin.com/gB30pbrC, as you see for example Vec.dot is a static method for the Vec class.

Comment: Actually I wonder how I could remake that Vec.js library I made with Class.js.

Comment: @Murplyx: Shouldn't be that hard, but it will involve slogging through all of your classes and updating the syntax, changing `this._super()` in `method` to `super.method()`, etc. You could also take advantage of arrow functions (much simpler, less error-prone `this` management). All of that transpiles without shims, so you could publish it without worrying about dependencies on Babel's shims. Some things, like `Promise` and `Map` and `Set` and `Symbol`, require sometimes-large shims, I wouldn't use them in a lib I was producing for non-ES2015 users.

Comment: @Murplyx: I think *this* question is answered, isn't it?